# How to check view scrollable position when scrollview scroll

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uiscrollview

We have implemented sticky out stream Ad functionality by using text view. When text view scroll we have show added one view in mid of text view text. And when textview scroll and added view is going out from view. then we have show another view with same content of added view. It works perfect. But now my new requirement is when user scroll the text view and added view appears. Then we need to show the second added view according to view appearance. like added view is only 50% appear on screen then we need to show the second view. Now my problem is how to detect the view appearance according to scroll position. for hide or show view.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method for that.
You can try with following:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    // Table View Scroll Image
    let viewContentOffset = textview.contentOffset
    let viewContentSize = textview.contentSize
    let viewBounds = textview.bounds.size

    // Use Alpha value to manipulation
    let bottomOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height
    let alpha = (scrollView.contentOffset.y / bottomOffset) * 2
}
```

Add Image to TextView using NSAttributtedString:

```
textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda."
let image = UIImage(named: "sampleImage.png");
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = image
let attString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
textView.textStorage.insert(attString, at: textView.text.count/2)
```

Comment: I want to show or hide second view according to added view visibility. When user scroll the textview

Comment: You can add hide/show view code inside given method. Alpha is the point that indicates on which point of scroll you have to hide/show the view.

Comment: But what about the added view. We need to show or hide second view according to added view visibility.

Comment: You can add it as subview on parent view. (not inside of textview)

Comment: we need to add in textview. without this we can't show view in between the textview text.

Comment: I do have an alternate idea, you can manage this situation through TableView without cell spacing, Suppose you have 100 characters in a paragraph. The first cell consist 50 Characters, the Second cell will have and Advt. and the Third cell will have remaining 50 characters.

Comment: @GauravGupta I have added another alternative to add an image using NSAttributedString.

Comment: This solution not solved my problem. because in View I have played a ad video.

Comment: So in that case the TableView approach seems suitable in your application.

Comment: Yes, But my requirement for textview